# C compiler written in java

Tags: java, c, compiler-construction

I want to integrate a c language compiler in to java application to compile c sources without file creation (Like Java Compiler Api). Is there any c compiler that has entirely written in java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check this link from Google Code [C compiler written in Java](https://code.google.com/archive/p/my-c-compiler/)

and say congratz to the developer :) -it's not me :p-

Another option is this one: [JCPP](http://www.anarres.org/projects/jcpp/)

Comment: Your link to github C compiler is not pointing to github, and the link is broken.

Comment: Fixed, thanks for the notification! (It's been a long time)

Answer (score 1):

ANTRL has a [grammar](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list) for C.  The problem of generating assembly code for a particular platform isn't solved for you, but you can walk the AST and emit the instructions provided you know what they should be.

Comment: Parsing the source into an AST is usually the easiest bit of a compiler. Semantic analysis and code generation would be a massive task.

Comment: I agree with that, Paul.  Code generation is platform-specific and difficult.

Comment: Actually. I don't want to implement this a platform independent application. I will use this in linux systems. I think ANTLER is a good solution but hard to implement as expected features.

Comment: By definition, a C compiler is platform dependent, because the generated assembly code is tied to the platform.  ANTLR won't help with assembly code generation, but neither will anything else.  This is a difficult problem if you understand it.

Comment: @duffymo: How is the machine code tied to the platform? That is an attribute of the current implementations, not of the [actual C standard](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2007/05/16/the-c-abstract-machine.aspx). Also, if you consider the x86 to be your VM-language, it is platform-independent already.

Comment: Your platform independent conclusion is based on the assumption "consider the x86 to be your VM-language".  I didn't make the assumption when I said that machine code was tied to the platform.  I realize that C the language is independent of the machine code that is generated for it.  I'm talking about the second step - machine code generation - after the C standard grammar has been used to parse the source into an AST.

Comment: You can choose to generate a platform independent compiled program, by choosing a virtual target instruction set, e.g., roll-you-own, possibly the JVM, possibly CIL.  That would make code generation some easier (except for pointer arithmetic which is likely to be hell for the JVM and CIL).

Comment: I don't see how this helps.  You have to write machine code sometime.  We're talking C here.  Why would I want to emit JVM or CIL instructions, which emit VMWare instructions, which emits OS instructions?  C is supposed to be close to the metal.  If I'm going to do all that I might as well just abandon C and write Java or C#.

Comment: No, you don't have to write machine code; the interpreter can do machine specific I/O, memory access, and OS calls.  Agreed, if you want to use C for arbitrary low-level metal, you have to be clear about what the *metal* is.  OP is pretty unclear about his goal here.

Comment: It's always been clear to me what metal is in the case of C: right down at the hardware level.  I would not put anything virtual between it and the hardware.  If I thought that was a good idea, I'd write Java or C# or Python.