# Is there any Java-based C/C++ compiler?

Tags: android, c++, linux, compiler-construction, dalvik

I understand that if it even exists it's N times slower than compiler written in native code and compiled for concrete arch. But anyway.

The main purpose is to compile few small c/c++ source files on android device (arm/x86, linux-based os, dalvik jvm). The sources can be created on users android device and compiler should work on users device too.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You don't need a compiler written in Java. You need a compiler that compiles code into Java bytecode. Those are two different things.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze I think he mean to compile the files ON the device, not to run on the device.

Comment: @fbafelipe Actually, you may be right!

Comment: There are a few compilers that run ON Android, but AFAIC the implementations are far from complete, good enough for playing perhaps. Your best option is to get some "cloud" solution that will do remote compilation to you and send you back the results.

Comment: I meant i need a compiler written in java, which compiles c/c++ sources (for AVR to be more detailed)

Comment: related to [C compiler written in java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6276976/309483)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after few weeks of research i can say there is no such thing in nature. For android you should use native compiler but you'l have a lot of compatibility issues so get ready to apply patches, catch exceptions and dive into hundreds of megabytes of native code..

Answer (score 2):

There is [C4droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.n0n3m4.droidc&hl=fr), which is an IDE and a C++ compiler on Android. Some plugins enable you to use libraries, such as the SDL, or to use gcc.

If you want to compile really small sources (1 file, no custom libs), you can use [codepad](http://codepad.org/) or [liveworkspace](http://liveworkspace.org/) to code on your smartphone. The code is not compiled as an executable, you just see the output (error, stdout, ...).

Comment: Thanks for the links, i will try it. Codepad and liveworkspace are online tools so they don't suit.

Answer (score 2):

If your objective is to compile c/c++ files on an android device, you can still use a C++ compiler written with C++ if you use [NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)

Comment: to use gcc for linux i don't need NDK - just execute gcc process with arguments. it's undesired as it requires ROOT permissions and it is platform-dependent as android devices can be ARM or x86

Comment: Running a native compiler on the device does not require root. But you would require multiple versions for the different platforms you wish to support. I think this is likely your best option.

Comment: sorry, what's native compiler? ndk compiler runs on developer machine and then compiled binary files are just copied in app resources. I need to compile the sources on user device as used is able to edit the sources.

Comment: @4ntoine By native compiler he mean compiler compiled in a native language (in this case C or C++). The idea was to port a C++ compiler to NDK, so you compile the *compiler code* on your developer computer, and you run the compiler on the device, so you can compile other sources.

Comment: oh, i did not catch that. That can probably be the right direction: compile avr-gcc using ndk to make it running on android devices

Answer (score 1):

I see several approaches to getting a compiler on your Android device:

## Linux on Android

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_Linux_Installer (the only one that requires root on this list)
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/gentooandroid/files/

## Full blown virtual machine

- [JPC for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.jads.android.jpc)
- [Limbo for Android](https://code.google.com/p/limbo-android/) (based on QEMU)

## Compiling to assembly and assembling

### From C source to assembly

- [my-c-compiler on Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/my-c-compiler/) (generates at&t x86 assembly)

### From assembly to native code

- https://code.google.com/p/dragonfire-dasm/

## Compiling to JVM bytecode and interpreting

### From C source to JVM bytecode

- [From C Source to Java Bytecode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459822/from-c-source-to-java-bytecode)

### JVM interpreters for the JVM

- https://github.com/lihaoyi/Metascala
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxine_Virtual_Machine
- maybe you could use the host JVM?